# App review video ( App Store )

Tags: video, ffmpeg, screen-resolution, quicktime

I want to convert a video recorded with Quick Time ( resolution 750*1334 ) to 1080*1920.
Apple only accept resolution 1080*1920p for iphone6PLUS for App review video.

My license key with final cut pro X has expired and
ffmpeg -i AppPreviewIphone6.mp4 -vf scale=1080:1920 AppPreviewIphone6PLUS.mp4 give me a resolution of 1079*1920 instead 1080*1920

Have you an idea what software I can use to change video resolution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
ffmpeg -i AppPreviewIphone6.mp4 -vf scale=1080:1920,setsar=1 AppPreviewIphone6PLUS.mp4
```

`scale` will adjust the aspect ratio flag to match the original display aspect ratio, and Quicktime/Apple considers the aspect-corrected dimensions. `750x1334` is not exactly 9:16 like `1080x1920` is, hence the `1079` being reported.